# After upgrading to Php 5.5.30 and Apache 2.4 Session eror

Tags: php, apache, session

Php 5.4 and Apache 2.2 all my website were working, after upgrading to php 5.5.30 and apache 2.4 I am getting these error message on log file on every domain on the server

```
[25-Nov-2015 01:55:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/qa-include/ajax/asktitle.php:76) in /home/mysite/public_html/qa-include/app/users.php on line 146
[25-Nov-2015 01:55:44 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/public_html/qa-include/ajax/asktitle.php:76) in /home/mysite/public_html/qa-include/app/users.php on line 183
```

What should I check on the server or where do I look at?

[Session info from phpinfo()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPvlJ.jpg)

Everything set correctly????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Well, even session path defined in server php.ini adding this little local php.ini to the domain root with session.save_path = "/home/mysite/tmp" fixed this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my host fixed the problem, 
Somehow, even session path defined in server php.ini adding this little local php.ini to the domain root with

```html
session.save_path = "/home/mysite/tmp"
```

fixed this problem...